# Why is Typescript expecting fetch()'s `body` property to be ReadableStream<Uint8Array>?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
  const request: RequestInfo = {
    method,
    cache,
    redirect,
    headers: {} as Headers,
    body: null as string | null,
  };

  ...

  fetch(url, request);
```

With the above, I get:

```
Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null'.
```

In TS's type declarations, there's:

```
interface RequestInit {
    /**
     * A BodyInit object or null to set request's body.
     */
    body?: BodyInit | null;
}

type BodyInit = Blob | BufferSource | FormData | URLSearchParams | ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | string;
```

Why is it expecting `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>`?

Answer (score 6):

*Not sure to completely understand your actual question, but let's answer both possibilities.*

The `RequestInfo` type is the one used for a *Request* instance, e.g

```
const request: RequestInfo = new Request(url, requestInit);
```

The object you are creating is actually the `requestInit` second parameter of `fetch`, and for this you need to use the `RequestInit` type.

```
const requestInit: RequestInit = {
  method,
  cache,
  redirect,
  headers: {} as Headers,
  body: null as string | null,
};
...
fetch(url, requestInit);
```

---

Now if you were wondering why the `RequestInit`'s `BodyInit` member says it can be a `ReadablStream<Uint8Array>`, that's because per specs it can, even though no browser supports it yet and [the specs are not really bullet-proof yet](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/pull/425).

Answer (score 2):

The definitions you show are not quite right, you show `RequestInit`, not `RequestInfo`. What I have (and what I could see on microsoft pages with TS definitions) is this

```
type RequestInfo = Request | string
```

```
interface Request extends Body {
  // No definition for `body` here
  // ...
}
```

```
interface Body {
  readonly body: ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null
  // ...
}
```

So it's clear, why the compiler complains. But it's not clear to me, why the definition is like so, because I'm sure it's possible to pass `string` as the `body` of a request. I think you will have to cast it to readable stream:

```
body: 'string' as unknown as ReadableStream<Uint8Array>
```

Or just cast it to `any`, because this type cast is pretty long. I don't think casting to `any` will cause any confusion, errors or problems here